# How do I hide pointer events but still be able to initiate a drag event?

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a simple image cropper, where you move the green box (the area to crop) over the red box (the original image). Here it is:

```js
var crop = document.querySelector(".image .crop");

crop.addEventListener("drag", function() {
  var mouseoffset = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
  crop.style.left = mouseoffset[0] + "px";
  crop.style.top = mouseoffset[1] + "px";
});
crop.addEventListener("dragend", function() {
  var mouseoffset = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
  crop.style.left = mouseoffset[0] + "px";
  crop.style.top = mouseoffset[1] + "px";
});
```

```css
.image {
  position:   relative;
  width:      400px;
  height:     400px;
  overflow:   hidden;
  background: #C00;
}

.image .crop {
  position:   absolute;
  width:      150px;
  height:     150px;
  background: rgba(64,168,36,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="crop" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

But there is a problem: you can notice a pale green box when dragging. I can hide it with `pointer-events: none`, but this renders the box undraggable. Is there any way I can hide this pale green box while still being able to drag the crop area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to adapt what you have going on with drag events to achieve that result, but I wasn't able to get it working. Here's something doing about the same thing but with `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `mousemove`.

```js
var crop = document.querySelector(".image .crop");

crop.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    moveBox(event);
  };
  document.onmouseup = function(event) {
    stopMoving(event);
  }
});

function moveBox(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var mouseoffset = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
  crop.style.left = mouseoffset[0] + "px";
  crop.style.top = mouseoffset[1] + "px";
}

function stopMoving(event) {
  document.onmousemove = null;
  document.onmouseup = null;
}
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #C00;
}

.image .crop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(64, 168, 36, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="crop" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, especially that `draggable="true"` is no longer needed.